# Edit- How can I add that when the answer is wrong it will turn red and green in the correct answer? Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode, var, let

Creates a quiz game

How can I add that when the answer is incorrect, the incorrect answer will turn red and the correct answer will turn green at the same time?

How can I make the colors disappear when the new question comes? I have it that when you press an answer, a new question will come right after that

EDIT: This code is working fine.

```
@IBOutlet var options: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIView!

var allQuestions = QuestionBank()
var Number: Int = 0
var selectedAnswer: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    oppdatertekst()
    options.forEach {
        $0.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        $0.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    feedback()
    if sender.tag == selectedAnswer {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        let riktig = NSLocalizedString("Quiz.riktig", comment: "")
        ProgressHUD.showSuccess(riktig)
    } else if let correctOption = options.first(where: { $0.tag == selectedAnswer }) {
        let feilnr = NSLocalizedString("Quiz.feilnr", comment: "")
        ProgressHUD.showError("\(feilnr)\(selectedAnswer)")
        correctOption.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        self.Number += 1
        self.oppdatertekst()
    }
}

func oppdaterSpm() {
if Number <= allQuestions.list.count - 1{
    questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[Number].question
    options.forEach {                
        $0.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    options[0].setTitle(allQuestions.list[Number].optionA, for: .normal)
    options[1].setTitle(allQuestions.list[Number].optionB, for: .normal)
    options[2].setTitle(allQuestions.list[Number].optionC, for: .normal)
    options[3].setTitle(allQuestions.list[Number].optionD, for: .normal)
    selectedAnswer = allQuestions.list[Number].correctAnswer
} else {
    let alert....
}
```

}

Comment: what is "it"?  "when the answer is wrong, it turns red"

Comment: Can you answer this?

Comment: U r playing hide & show with 4 options within one ViewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having four `IBOutlet`s use [`IBOutletCollection`](https://youtu.be/9cLk5Waf8qY?t=340) and connect these four buttons to this collection.

In `answerPressed` method if the correct answer is selected change clicked button color to green. If the wrong answer is selected change selected answer color to red, then get the correct answer button from the collection and change its color to green. After 5 seconds reload next question.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var options: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIView!

    var allQuestions = QuestionBank()
    var Number: Int = 0
    var selectedAnswer: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        oppdatertekst()
        options.forEach {
            $0.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            $0.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        feedback()
        if sender.tag == selectedAnswer {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            let riktig = NSLocalizedString("Quiz.riktig", comment: "")
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess(riktig)
        } else if let correctOption = options.first(where: { $0.tag == selectedAnswer }) {
            let feilnr = NSLocalizedString("Quiz.feilnr", comment: "")
            ProgressHUD.showError("\(feilnr)\(selectedAnswer)")
            correctOption.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            Number += 1
            oppdatertekst()
        }        
    }
}
```

Change all buttons color in `oppdaterSpm` method

```
func oppdaterSpm() {
    if Number <= allQuestions.list.count - 1{
        questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[Number].question
        options.forEach {                
            $0.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        options[0].setTitle(allQuestions.list[Number].optionA, for: .normal)
        options[1].setTitle(allQuestions.list[Number].optionB, for: .normal)
        options[2].setTitle(allQuestions.list[Number].optionC, for: .normal)
        options[3].setTitle(allQuestions.list[Number].optionD, for: .normal)
        selectedAnswer = allQuestions.list[Number].correctAnswer
    } else {
        let alert....
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so far, i have changed my code, the last code did not join, can you look at it?

Comment: if Number <= allQuestions.list.count - 1{  this code, I did not see that this code was not included when I wrote down the code in the first place

Comment: thanks for the help, i get an error message on this code  correctOption.backgroundColor = UIColor.green "Value of type 'Array<Element>.Index' (aka 'Int') has no member 'backgroundColor'"

Comment: everything works fine, I have tried to add the other buttons since I have 4 tooling gov arrange answer but it only comes up an answer to all buttons, something I've done wrong? since only one answer is visible? have updated my code

Comment: I have updated my code if u can check it, since all my buttons show just one answer but I have 4 different answer in a question bank

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you helped me a lot. Everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `UIButton` changes in common method. Call it anywhere.

**When New Question Comes:**

```
func whenNewQuestionComes() {

    optionA.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    optionA.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    optionA.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    optionB.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    optionB.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    optionB.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    optionC.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    optionC.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    optionC.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    optionD.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    optionD.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    optionD.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

}
```

**Show Green and Red**

```
@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    feedback()

    optionA.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    optionB.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    optionC.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    optionD.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    if sender.tag == selectedAnswer {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        let riktig = NSLocalizedString("Quiz.riktig", comment: "")
        ProgressHUD.showSuccess(riktig)
    } 
    /*
    else if let correctOption = options.first(where: { $0.tag == selectedAnswer }) {
        let feilnr = NSLocalizedString("Quiz.feilnr", comment: "")
        ProgressHUD.showError("\(feilnr)\(selectedAnswer)")
        correctOption.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    */
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        self.Number += 1
        self.oppdatertekst()
    }
}
```